# Testing an async method with no callback in mocha

Tags: javascript, testing, asynchronous, mocha.js, sinon

I have an async method with runs a DB query and then writes to a log. It doesn't return anything, and doesn't have a need for a callback.

I *could* add a callback purely for tests, but my preference would be to spy on the log method and pass or fail the test based on that, rather than add functionality purely for tests

```
TestableMode.method = function() {


TestableMode.asyncThing(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        TestableMode.log.error('Log Error', {
            'error': err
        });
    } else {
        TestableMode.log.info('Write results');

    }
});
```

};

Currently, I am using mocha to run my tests. In other tests I have used sinon to spy on methods, can I use these spys as a trigger for the assertions? Can I pass a test as soon as `TestableMode.log.info` is called, and fail it as soon as `TestableMode.log.error` is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sinon to spy the "TestableMode.log.info" instead of introducing a callback purely for the testing purpose.If its difficult to achieve the assertion on spying the log.info you can even try emitting an success and error event's in DB query's callback such that you can call mocha's done call back when the event gets emitted.